# Page break inside grouping

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have implemented tablix inside tablix concept. I done this with the help of following [link](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/03/ssrs-how-to-show-tablix-inside-tablix.html).

I have one table A, that is holding other two tables B & C respectively. I have grouped these two tables with the help of Dept_Nbr from first table A.

[image: Table Structure in Report]

**What I want is:**

I want to give page break in between two tables. For example, I have Dept_Nbr as 529 and 530. In one page, the two tables will show the records for 529 and in the other page the two tables will show the records for 530.

Now I want to show all these records in four pages. first table is in one page and second table is in other page for 529th Dept_nbr and vice versa for 530.

How to give Page break inside grouping.

**What I tried is:**

1. I gave Page Break on Group Properties, Hence Page is breaking in between two groups. But I want a page break inside a group itself.
2. Also I checked the check box on tablix properties i.e.., Add Page Break Before and Add Page Break After. But nothing gives the output as it is already in grouping.

Please guide me on the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parent group to Table A that encompasses the rows containing Tables B & C. For this parent group, group on Department Number. Then, as part of the group properties, you can have it break between groups.

As your question and layout stands now, you're asking that the report break between detail rows. As far as I know, this is not possible.

Comment: You are correct. I too did the same. I have created the parent group to the table A, with that I made page break. Thanks for your Information.